# Product of numbers is even , when an unbiased die rolled?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, products, dice

An unbiased die is thrown $n$ times. The probability that the product of numbers would be even is

1. $1/(2n)$
2. $1/[(6n)!]$
3. $1−6^{−n}$
4. $6^{−n}$
5. None of the above.

---

#### My attempt :

we have $3$ even number and $3$ odd number in the an unbiased dice , i.e. $2,4,6$ and $1,3,5$ respectively .

Probability to occur odd number , i.e. P(odd) $= \cfrac{1}{2}$

As we know , if all numbers are odd then product of these number will be odd , else even , in other words , if at least one even number occur then product of these number will be even .

Therefore , required probability is ,

$=$ probability for at least one even number occur

$= 1 -$ probability for all odd number occur

$= 1 - \left(\cfrac{1}{2}\right)^n$

---

> Product of numbers is even , when an unbiased die rolled ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @cr001 dear , I need an verification (regarding the post).

Comment: Your solution $1-{1\over2}^n$ is correct, what more do you want?

Comment: The answer is none of the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

There's not much left to do with it, except perhaps writing it down slightly more "tidy".

---

Calculate $1$ minus the probability of the complementary event:

- The probability of getting an odd number in a roll is $\frac36$
- The probability of getting an odd product in $n$ rolls is $\left(\frac36\right)^n$
- The probability of getting an even product in $n$ rolls is $1-\left(\frac36\right)^n$

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: You're welcome.